# Getting all items using a Specific Sublayout using Sitecore Powershell Extensions

Tags: sitecore-client, powershell-extensions, sitecore-query

I have to get data of rendering parameters used by a specific sub-layout. Is there a way to get all items which are using a particular Sublayout.

Example:
I have a Sublayout "SiteHeader" and it has a rendering parameter template with a parameter "show image" checkbox.
I need to fetch all the items which are using this "SiteHeader" Sublayout and the value of "show image" field i.e. if it is checked or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can. I would go through the Links database in order to do that, like this:

```
$rendering = Get-Item -Path '{093B75B4-5060-4F3D-AFAB-DCA4999F7E96}'
$items = @()
[Sitecore.Globals]::LinkDatabase.GetReferrers($rendering) | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.SourceFieldId -eq '{04BF00DB-F5FB-41F7-8AB7-22408372A981}' -or $_.SourceFieldId -eq '{F1A1FE9E-A60C-4DDB-A3A0-BB5B29FE732E}' } | 
    Select-Object -Property SourceItemID -Unique |
    ForEach-Object {
        $item = Get-Item -Path $_.SourceItemId
        #you can add further filtering code here
        $items += $item
    }

$items
```

Replace the ID on the first line with your Sublayouts ID. Then that goes to the link database to find all items that links to this item, filters them to only take the shared and final renderings fields, and selects the unique rows. Then it gets all the items and adds it to an array.

edit: made it a bit clearer and fetched the items rather than just the ids

Answer (score 2):

Likely very similar output as @morten.engel's response, but Sitecore Powershell Extensions has a `Get-ItemReferrer` [command](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/get-itemreferrer):

```
$allReferrers = Get-ItemReferrer -ID '{093B75B4-5060-4F3D-AFAB-DCA4999F7E96}'
```

The above will return *all* referrers to the item specified by the `ID`.  If you need to filter the referrers based on additional fields:

```
$checkedReferrers = Get-ItemReferrer -ID '{093B75B4-5060-4F3D-AFAB-DCA4999F7E96}' | Where-Object {$_.Fields["Show Image"].Value -eq 'checked'}
```

Also, if you *need* to know or filter based on the actual field *referencing* the specific item, `Get-ItemReferrer` also has a `-ItemLink` switch that will return `Links` instead of `Items` (almost exact to @morten.engel's answer):

```
$filteredFieldReferrers = Get-ItemReferrer -ID '{093B75B4-5060-4F3D-AFAB-DCA4999F7E96}' -ItemLink 
| Where-Object { $_.SourceFieldId -eq '{04BF00DB-F5FB-41F7-8AB7-22408372A981}' -or $_.SourceFieldId -eq '{F1A1FE9E-A60C-4DDB-A3A0-BB5B29FE732E}' } 
| Select-Object -Property SourceItemID -Unique | Get-Item
```